# If p and q are distinct prime numbers, it is true that we always have $p^{q-1}+q^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod pq$?

Tags: number-theory

If p and q are distinct prime numbers, it is true that we always have $p^{q-1}+q^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod pq$? More generally if $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ are relatively prime, is it true that $n^{\phi(m)}+m^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod mn$?

First, I experimented with the different numbers for each of the statements. I found for the first statement that when p=1 and q=2 then $p^{q-1}+q^{p-1}=1^{2-1}+2^{1-1}=1+1 \equiv 0 \mod 2$. Hence the first statement is not true.

But for the second statement when m=1 and n=2, the statement is still true. I know that if m is prime then $\phi(m)=m^1-m^{1-1}=m-1$ because of $\phi(m^k)=m^k-m^{k-1}$. Similarly, we find $\phi(n)=n-1$ when n is prime. Then $n^{\phi(m)}+m^{\phi(n)}=n^{m-1}+m^{n-1}$ which is the same as the first statement. Why is this happening? Shouldn't it fail just like the first statement?

Comment: 1 is not generally considered to be prime.

Comment: So then my claim is wrong. The first equation has solution?

Comment: Yes, your more general equation is true. Simply consider the equation modulo $m$ and $n$ separately.

Comment: In your case with one and two, I see the problem that $2^{1-1}\equiv 0^{1-1}$ modulo $2$ can be seen as zero or one. Sometimes, one convention is useful and other times the other.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein. So this is a case where you would implement chinese remainder theorem, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the statement about primes is a special case of the statement for general (relatively prime) $m,n$.

Actually, both statements are always true.

I think about this as follows:

If $m,n$ are relatively prime, then $m$ is a unit of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\varphi(n)$ is the order of the unit group of this ring, $m^{\varphi(n)}$ is definitely $1$ mod $n$.  Meanwhile, $n^{\varphi(m)}$ is a multiple of $n$ since $\varphi(m)\geq 1$, thus

$$m^{\varphi(n)} + n^{\varphi(m)} = m^{\varphi(n)} = 1\mod n$$

The same argument with $m$ and $n$ reversed shows that $m^{\varphi(n)} + n^{\varphi(m)} = 1\mod m$.  By the Chinese remainder theorem, there is a unique residue mod $mn$ that is 1 mod $m$ and $n$; clearly it is $1$.  Thus $m^{\varphi(n)}+n^{\varphi(m)}$, being $1$ mod $m$ and mod $n$, is $1$ mod $mn$.